# Draw cubes with random colors using OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I want every cube to have a random color but with this code the colors keep changing all the time

```
int espacioX = -500;
int espacioY = -500;
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
    for(int j=1; j<=100; j++){
        randomR = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
        randomG = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
        randomB = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
        glColor3f(randomR,randomG,randomB);
        glTranslatef(espacioX,espacioY,0);
        glutSolidCube(9);
        glTranslatef(-espacioX,-espacioY,0);
        espacioX+=10;
    }
    glTranslatef(-1000,0,0);
    espacioY+=10;
}
```

How do I make them stay in the same color while the program is running?

Edit:
This is the comple code:

```
#include <windows.h>

/***** OpenGL library imports. *****/
#include<gl\glut.h>                                 //basic header file for OpenGL 
//#include <gl\glaux.h>                             // Header File For The Glaux Library
/***** C library imports. *****/ 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>



int ScreenWidth  = 0;
int ScreenHeight = 0; 
int last_x = 0, last_y = 0,left = 1,middle = 0,right = 0;
int zoom_y = 0;
int anglex=0, angley=0, anglez=0;
int lookfrom=450;
int ang=0;


void myGlutKeyboard(unsigned char Key, int x, int y)
{
    printf("%5d\n",Key);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void init_GL_params()
{
    static GLfloat light_ambient[] = { .250, .250, .250, .250 };
    static GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { .250, .250, .25, .250 };
    static GLfloat light_specular[] = { .250, .250, .250, .250 };

    static GLfloat light1_diffuse[] = { .250, .250, .250, .0 };
    static GLfloat light1_specular[] = { .250, .250, .250, .0 };

    glEnable (GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHT1);
    glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc (GL_LESS);
    glEnable (GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace (GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace (GL_CCW);

    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
    glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE,  light1_diffuse); 
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, light1_specular);
    glLightfv (GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);

    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

}

void setLightPosition()
{
    static GLfloat light_position[] = { 100, 200.0, 10, 1.0 };
    static GLfloat light1_position[] = { -0.0, 300.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

    // set the light position (for some reason we have to do this in model view.
    glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light1_position);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); 
}

void myGlutDisplay(void)
{
    init_GL_params();

      // clear the window
    glClearColor (0,0,0,0); //Color de fondo R G B
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    setLightPosition();     //Posici{on de la fuente de luz
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0f, 1.0, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
    gluLookAt(                          //punto de vista
            0 ,100 ,lookfrom ,          // desde donde veo xyz
            0, 0, 0,                    // hacia donde veo xyz
            0,1,0 ); 
    glRotatef(anglex, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(angley, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(anglez, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    //Empieza a dibujar
    int espacioX = 500;
    int espacioY = 500;
    double randomR, randomG, randomB;

    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=100; j++){
            randomR = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
            randomG = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
            randomB = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
            glColor3f(randomR,randomG,randomB);
            glTranslatef(espacioX,espacioY,0);
            glutSolidCube(9);
            glTranslatef(-espacioX,-espacioY,0);
            espacioX-=10;
        }
        glTranslatef(1000,0,0);       
        espacioY-=10;
    }

    glFlush();                                          // Flush The GL Pipeline
    glutSwapBuffers();  
}

void myGlutReshape2(int mWidth, int mHeight)
{
    ScreenWidth  = mWidth;
    ScreenHeight = mHeight;
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) ScreenWidth, (GLsizei) ScreenHeight);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


/****************************************************************/
void myGlutIdle(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

/***************************************************************/

void myGlutMouse(int button, int button_state, int x, int y){
  if ( (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (button_state == GLUT_DOWN) ) 
  {
    last_x = x;
    last_y = y;
    left = 1;
    middle = 0;
    right = 0;
  }
  else if ((button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) && (button_state == GLUT_DOWN) ) 
  {
      zoom_y = y;
      right = 1;
      left = 0;
      middle = 0;
  }
}

void myGlutMotion(int x, int y){
        if (left){
            anglex+= (float) (y - last_y);
            angley+= (float) (x - last_x);

            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
        }
        if (right)
        {
            lookfrom += (y - zoom_y);
            zoom_y = y;
        }
}

void GlutInit(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ScreenWidth  = 700;
    ScreenHeight = 700;
    /****************************************/
    /*   Initialize GLUT and create window  */
    /****************************************/
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_STENCIL );   //set up the display as a double buffer using RGB values
    glutInitWindowPosition(90, 50);                 //set the position of where you want the window to open
    glutInitWindowSize(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);  //set how big you want the initial window to be
    glutCreateWindow("Testing Virtual Environment" );   //what do you want the window to be called (titlebar text)

    //register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(myGlutDisplay);         //Register the display callback
    glutReshapeFunc(myGlutReshape2);        // -- Resize handler
    glutKeyboardFunc(myGlutKeyboard);       // -- Keyboard handler
    glutMouseFunc(myGlutMouse);             // -- Mouse Click handler
    glutMotionFunc(myGlutMotion);           // -- Mous motion handler
    glutIdleFunc(myGlutIdle);               // -- Idle handler

  glFlush();
}


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    GlutInit(argc, argv);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

It was a sample code so I just posted the part that I edited, sorry. When I did a cube or a sphere with an specific color it always stayed the same so i didn't realiza that this refresh the image all the time. I don't really understand the whole thing so I don't know where it's refreshing the image.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Make a 100x100 array of colors, fill with with random colors *once*. Then use `[i-1][j-1]`th colors for corresponding cubes.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Why close ? the question is clear and even the first chunk of code tells everything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set `SEED` to some constant value at start of `myGlutDisplay(void)`. That will give you the same random values each frame without any big change in your code for example like this:

```
void myGlutDisplay(void)
{
    init_GL_params();

      // clear the window
    glClearColor (0,0,0,0); //Color de fondo R G B
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    setLightPosition();     //Posici{on de la fuente de luz
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0f, 1.0, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
    gluLookAt(                          //punto de vista
            0 ,100 ,lookfrom ,          // desde donde veo xyz
            0, 0, 0,                    // hacia donde veo xyz
            0,1,0 ); 
    glRotatef(anglex, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(angley, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(anglez, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    //Empieza a dibujar
    int espacioX = 500;
    int espacioY = 500;
    double randomR, randomG, randomB;

    srand(0x98765432); // this is the SEED

    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=100; j++){
            randomR = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
            randomG = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
            randomB = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX);
            glColor3f(randomR,randomG,randomB);
            glTranslatef(espacioX,espacioY,0);
            glutSolidCube(9);
            glTranslatef(-espacioX,-espacioY,0);
            espacioX-=10;
        }
        glTranslatef(1000,0,0);       
        espacioY-=10;
    }

    glFlush();                                          // Flush The GL Pipeline
    glutSwapBuffers();  
}
```

The value of the `SEED` will give you the pattern. So changing the constant will change the colors. Beware wrong constant (like 0) can corrupt the randomness of the `rand()` function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are running this code inside another loop which means you are calculating your random variables every time the scene is redrawn, this would cause the colors to change and the obvious solution would be to poulate your list of cubes once and then iterate through the list drawing the cubes on each scene refresh.

However, without seeing the rest of your code it is unclear.  Please include more information so we can give you a better answer.

Comment: I added the whole code because I'm not sure what part it's doing it.